# sendto sends garbage (VBA)

Tags: vba, sendto

I am reusing the code from [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?524835-Send-UDP-Packets-in-VBA) with some changes - added *private* keyword to some definitions because Excel VBA was reporting errors and changed type to IPRAW/ICMP.

At the end I see garbage in the wireshark *in the data section* of the packet, however data size is correct (3 bytes). I checked that sendBuf is really containing first bytes as three 'a' when sendTo is executed. What is wrong?

Data is sent using `CommandButton1_Click()` sub at the bottom of the listing.

Here's the code

```
'reference
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673(v=vs.85).aspx
Const INVALID_SOCKET = -1
Const WSADESCRIPTION_LEN = 256

Enum AF
  AF_UNSPEC = 0
  AF_INET = 2
  AF_IPX = 6
  AF_APPLETALK = 16
  AF_NETBIOS = 17
  AF_INET6 = 23
  AF_IRDA = 26
  AF_BTH = 32
End Enum

Enum sock_type
   SOCK_STREAM = 1
   SOCK_DGRAM = 2
   SOCK_RAW = 3
   SOCK_RDM = 4
   SOCK_SEQPACKET = 5
End Enum

Enum Protocol
   IPPROTO_ICMP = 1
   IPPROTO_IGMP = 2
   BTHPROTO_RFCOMM = 3
   IPPROTO_TCP = 6
   IPPROTO_UDP = 17
   IPPROTO_ICMPV6 = 58
   IPPROTO_RM = 113
End Enum

'Type sockaddr
'   sa_family As Integer
'   sa_data(0 To 13) As Byte
'End Type

Private Type sockaddr_in
  sin_family As Integer
  sin_port As Integer
  sin_addr(0 To 3) As Byte
  sin_zero(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Type socket
   pointer As Long
End Type

Private Type LPWSADATA_Type
   wVersion As Integer
   wHighVersion As Integer
   szDescription(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
   szSystemStatus(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
   iMaxSockets As Integer
   iMaxUdpDg As Integer
   lpVendorInfo As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function WSAGetLastError Lib "Ws2_32.dll" () As Integer
Private Declare Function WSAStartup Lib "Ws2_32.dll" (ByVal wVersionRequested As Integer, ByRef lpWSAData As LPWSADATA_Type) As Long
Private Declare Function sendto Lib "Ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, ByRef buf() As Byte, ByVal length As Long, ByVal flags As Long, ByRef toaddr As sockaddr_in, tolen As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function f_socket Lib "Ws2_32.dll" Alias "socket" (ByVal AF As Long, ByVal stype As Long, ByVal Protocol As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function closesocket Lib "Ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub WSACleanup Lib "Ws2_32.dll" ()

Sub SendPacket(Message As String, IP As String, Port As Integer)
   Dim ConnectSocket As socket
   Dim wsaData As LPWSADATA_Type
   Dim iResult As Integer: iResult = 0
   Dim send_sock As sock_type: send_sock = INVALID_SOCKET
   Dim iFamily As AF: iFamily = AF_INET
   Dim iType As Integer: iType = SOCK_RAW 'SOCK_UDP
   Dim iProtocol As Integer: iProtocol = IPPROTO_ICMP 'IPPROTO_UDP
   Dim SendBuf(0 To 1023) As Byte
   Dim BufLen As Integer: BufLen = 1024
   Dim RecvAddr As sockaddr_in: RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET: RecvAddr.sin_port = Port
   Dim SplitArray As Variant: SplitArray = Split(IP, ".")

   RecvAddr.sin_addr(0) = SplitArray(0)
   RecvAddr.sin_addr(1) = SplitArray(1)
   RecvAddr.sin_addr(2) = SplitArray(2)
   RecvAddr.sin_addr(3) = SplitArray(3)


   For buf = 1 To Len(Message)
      SendBuf(buf - 1) = Asc(Mid(Message, buf, 1))
   Next buf
   SendBuf(buf + 1) = 0

   iResult = WSAStartup(&H202, wsaData)
   If iResult <> 0 Then
      MsgBox ("WSAStartup failed: " & iResult)
      Exit Sub
   End If

   send_sock = f_socket(iFamily, iType, iProtocol)
   If send_sock = INVALID_SOCKET Then
      Errno = WSAGetLastError()
      Exit Sub
   End If

   iResult = sendto(send_sock, SendBuf, Len(Message), 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr)) ' BufLen, 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr))
   If iResult = -1 Then
      MsgBox ("sendto failed with error: " & WSAGetLastError())
      closesocket (send_sock)
      Call WSACleanup
      Exit Sub
   End If

   iResult = closesocket(send_sock)
   If iResult <> 0 Then
      MsgBox ("closesocket failed with error : " & WSAGetLastError())
      Call WSACleanup
   End If
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call SendPacket("aaa", "192.168.1.55", 1000)
End Sub
```

**Update:** As per Remy Lebeau's advice I did the following changes

```
Private Declare Function sendto Lib "Ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal buf As LongPtr, ByVal length As Long, ByVal flags As Long, ByRef toaddr As sockaddr_in, tolen As Long) As Long
```

changing `ByRef buf() As Byte` with `ByVal buf As LongPtr`,

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias "VarPtr" (Var() As Any) As LongPtr
...
iResult = sendto(send_sock, VarPtrArray(SendBuf) + 12, Len(Message), 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr))
```

changing `SendBuf` to `VarPtrArray(SendBuf) + 12`.

but I still get the garbage.

**Update 2:** success:

added

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias "VarPtr" (Var() As Any) As LongPtr
```

modified

```
iResult = sendto(send_sock, VarPtr(SendBuf(0)), Len(Message), 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr))
```

Comment: There are no static arrays in VBA, they are always allocated dynamically.

Comment: `VarPtrArray(SendBuf) + 12` is still not correct.  Did you even READ the articles I directed you to? The [Array Variables](http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-array-variables-and-pointers-in-depth/) article shows you exactly how to use `VarPtrArray()` correctly

Comment: I read, but I hardly understand that. I took already existing code from the web, and it did not work. You write that I need to read from offset +12, and then it appears to be wrong too. I just need a solution. And thank you for guiding me to it. Now I am able to send valid ping request.

Comment: "*You write that I need to read from offset +12, and then it appears to be wrong too*" - because you didn't do it CORRECTLY. You did not read and comprehend what the articles were explaining to you. Go back and read them again more carefully. "*I just need a solution*" - I gave you one. The articles even had detailed code examples, which you clearly skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong memory address in the `buf` parameter of `sendto()`, so it retrieves bytes from the wrong memory.  That is why you see "garbage" in the packet payload.

Your use of `ByRef buf() as Byte` for the `buf` parameter of `sendto()` is all wrong.  `sendto()` expects a pointer directly to the actual bytes to be sent.  But your `SendBuf` variable is a dynamic array (it is a wrapper for a COM [`SAFEARRAY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482.aspx) containing a pointer to the actual bytes).  By passing `SendBuf` as-is using `ByRef`, you are actually passing `sendto()` the memory address of your `SendBuf` variable itself, not the memory address of the byte data (located elsewhere in memory) that `SendBuf` refers to.

From [VBA Internals: What’s in a variable](http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-whats-in-a-variable/):

> Arrays in VBA are built from at least 3 pointers. First, calling `VarPtrArray()` on a array variable will get you the address to the variable content. If you directly read the variable content you will get another pointer — to the start of a `SAFEARRAY` struct. Finally, if you directly read from byte offset 12 (the `pvData` field) of the `SAFEARRAY`, you will get **a pointer to the start of the array elements data**.

That last value ("a pointer to the start of the array elements data") is the memory address that you need to pass to the `buf` parameter of `sendto()`.  So, change the `buf` parameter to [`LongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/longptr-data-type), and then use a combination of `VarPtrArray()` and `CopyMemory()` to extract the pointer to the byte data from `SendBuf`'s internal `SAFEARRAY`.

See [VBA Internals: Getting Pointers](http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-getting-pointers/) (which provides the appropriate declaration for `VarPtrArray()` depending on your version of Office), and [VBA Internals: Array Variables and Pointers in Depth](http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-array-variables-and-pointers-in-depth/) (which shows you how to use `VarPtrArray()` to get the internal data pointer from an array variable).

For example:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias "VarPtr" (Var() As Any) As LongPtr
' Public Declare Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE6" Alias "VarPtr" (Var() As Any) As Long
...
Private Declare Function sendto Lib "Ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal buf As LongPtr, ByVal length As Long, ByVal flags As Long, ByRef toaddr As sockaddr_in, tolen As Long) As Long
...

Dim SendBuf(0 To 1023) As Byte
Dim ptrToArrayVar As LongPtr
Dim ptrToSafeArray As LongPtr
Dim ptrToArrayData As LongPtr
Dim uSAFEARRAY As SAFEARRAY_VECTOR

...

' Get pointer to array *variable*
ptrToArrayVar = VarPtrArray(SendBuf)

' Get the pointer to the *SAFEARRAY* by directly
' reading the variable's address
CopyMemory ptrToSafeArray, ByVal ptrToArrayVar, PTR_LENGTH

' Read the SAFEARRAY struct
CopyMemory uSAFEARRAY, ByVal ptrToSafeArray, LenB(uSAFEARRAY)

' Get the pointer to the actual vector of bytes
ptrToArrayData = uSAFEARRAY.pvData

iResult = sendto(send_sock, ptrToArrayData, buf + 1, 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr))
```

**Update**: apparently, you don't need to access the `SAFEARRAY` directly at all.  `VarPtr()` is able to get the memory address of a specific element of an array variable.  So, you can use the following instead to get the memory address of the first byte in `SendBuf` (which is effectively the same memory address that the internal `SAFEARRAY` points to):

```
iResult = sendto(send_sock, VarPtr(SendBuf(0)), buf + 1, 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr))
```

Comment: VarPtrArray: "sub or function is not defined". I will greatly appreciate if you just write the lines how they must look like and explain why.

Comment: Obviously, you didn't read the [Getting Pointers](http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-getting-pointers/) article I linked to: "*Due to VBA’s syntax, there is no way to directly pass an array variable to `VarPtr`. **In order to get a pointer to an array variable you must declare an alternate form of `VarPtr`, traditionally aliased as `VarPtrArray`**. Naturally you could call it anything you want.*" And it gives you the actual declaration of `VarPtrArray`. The [Array Variables](http://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-array-variables-and-pointers-in-depth/) article then shows you how to use `VarPtrArray`

Comment: Updated the question, I still get the garbage in the packet data field.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The method `sendto` takes the address of the beginning of data in your buffer.

Declare the argument with `ByRef buffer As Any`:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function sendto Lib "Ws2_32.dll" ( _
    ByVal socket As Long, _
    ByRef buffer As Any, _
    ByVal length As Long, _
    ByVal flags As Long, _
    ByRef toaddr As Any, _
    ByVal tolen As Long) As Long
```

and provide the first element by reference:

```
Dim buffer() As Byte, size As Long

buffer = StrConv(Message, vbFromUnicode)  ' UTF-16 2 bytes to ANSI 1 byte
size = UBound(buffer) + 1

iResult = sendto(send_sock, buffer(0), size, 0, RecvAddr, Len(RecvAddr))
```